# Are photos of WWII US Navy damage reports available online?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, military, naval, photography

I have located [a PDF](http://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USN/rep/WDR/U.S.S.%20MARBLEHEAD%20%28CL-2%29,%20BOMB%20DAMAGE%20-%20Java%20Sea,%20February%204,%201942.pdf) of the USS *Marblehead*'s Bomb Damage Report from 4 Feb 1942. The report lists plates of photographs which are not included in the report I have found.

Do copies of this report exist online that include the photos? I have found for-pay sites that also host the report but am reticent to make a purchase without knowing for sure that the photos are included.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry on [USS Marblehead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Marblehead_%28CL-12%29) (CL-12) includes one relevant black-and-white photo. If you look up its [provenance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USS_Marblehead_%28CL-12%29.jpg) (U.S. Navy photograph 80-G-237439) this points (indirectly) to a couple of other relevant sites, e.g. [here](http://www.history.navy.mil/photos/sh-usn/usnsh-m/cl12.htm). A collection of the verbatim damage report photos mentioned in the report is (seemingly) not a among them, though.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I've found a couple on [WWII Archives](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/).

[USS Enterprise (CV-6) War Damage Report - 5 September 1942 (Eastern Solomons)](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/servlet/action/document/index/1420/0) - War damage report of Captain A. C. Davis of details of damage to USS Enterprise (CV-6) as a result of three direct hits during the Battle of the Eastern Solomons, 24 August 1942.

[USS Enterprise (CV-6) War Damage Report - 8 November 1942 (Eastern Solomons)](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/servlet/action/document/index/1421/0) - Captain O. B. Hardison's report of damage from 2 direct hits and several near misses which caused extensive damage to USS Enterprise (CV-6). Photographs of damage are enclosed.

[USS Hornet (CV-8) War Damage Report - October 26, 1942 (Santa Cruz)](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/servlet/action/document/index/1277/0) - War Damage Report for Hornet (CV-8). Loss in Action. Santa Cruz. 26 October 1942

[USS Lexington (CV-2) War Damage Report - June 15, 1942 (Coral Sea)](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/servlet/action/document/index/1313/0) - War Damage Report for Lexington (CV-2) Coral Sea. 15 October 1942

[USS Yorktown (CV-5) War Damage Report - 28 November 1942 (Coral Sea)](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/servlet/action/document/index/1286/0) - War Damage Report for Yorktown (CV-5). Bomb Damage. Coral Sea. May 8, 1942.

[USS Yorktown (CV-5) War Damage Report - May 20, 1942 (Coral Sea)](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/servlet/action/document/index/1284/0) - War Damage Report for Yorktown (CV-5). May 20, 1942.

[USS Yorktown (CV-5) War Damage Report - March 9, 1943 (Midway)](http://www.wwiiarchives.net/servlet/action/document/index/1283/0) - War Damage Report for Yorktown (CV-5). Loss in Action. Midway. June 4-7, 1942.

In fact, this website has plenty of information, including Action Reports, War Diaries, Casualty Lists, Code Books and Intelligence Summaries and Intercepts and a fair bit more.